# ArcGIS Error: ERROR 000223: Cannot extract event table properties while trying to create an event layer using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, dbf, error-000223

I have a .dbf file and want to change it to a .shp file with its LAT/LON.

ArcPy Code,

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
dbffile = "GIS_counts.dbf"

spref =  arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) #gcs_wgs_1984
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management (dbffile, "LONGITUD", "LATITUDE", "test.shp", spref)
```

Error:

```
ERROR 000223: Cannot extract event table properties
Failed to execute (MakeXYEventLayer).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to go directly from a dbf to a shp with that tool.  The tool creates a *feature layer* as its output which is *temporary*, you then have to call a CopyFeatures to save the output as a shapefile.  Have a look at the code sample in the [online help documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-xy-event-layer.htm).

I think you will also need to create a table view of the dbf to use as input, so that the tool can correctly interpret the table.

Try making the following changes to your script:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
dbffile = "GIS_counts.dbf"

# Add
dbftable = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(dbffile, "dbftable")

spref =  arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) #gcs_wgs_1984

# Edit
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management (dbftable , "LONGITUD", "LATITUDE", "xyLayer", spref)

# Add
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("xyLayer", "test.shp")
```